# Infinity $\times\ 0=$ ? indeterminate or zero?

Tags: limits, infinity

I got the following equation for a differential solution
$$Q= e^{-Rt/2L} (A \cos wt + B \sin wt)$$
where $R,L,w,A,B$ are constants.
If $t$ tends to infinity, find $Q$?

$e^{-Rt/2L} = 0$, if $t$ tends to infinity
$(A \cos wt + B \sin wt) = \infty$, if $t$ tends to infinity is it?
So $Q = \infty \times 0$, that is indeterminate.

then what is the value for $Q$, if $t$ tends to infinity?

The answer was $Q =0$. How? Explain me?

Comment: Is not $-1\le \cos \le 1?$ And $-1\le \sin \le 1?$

Comment: Shouldn't you already know basic limits theory **before** differential equations?

Comment: Indeterminate means "knowing it has this form is not enough to tell you the answer". $0*\infty $ is indeterminate, but that doesn't stop the answer to a particular limit from being 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By triangle inequality, you have

$$\forall t\in \mathbb R\;\; |Q(t)|\leq (|A|+|B|)e^{-\frac{Rt}{2L}}$$

since $|\cos(wt)|\leq 1, |\sin(wt)|\leq 1$.

and

$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}e^{-\frac{Rt}{2L}}=0$$

if $R.L>0$.
thus

$$\lim_{t\to +\infty}Q(t)=0.$$

Comment: if t tends to infinity sin t is?

Comment: @Nisha Bounded.

Comment: Got it. thank u